# second homology class in an oriented smooth simply connected 4-manifold

Tags: gt.geometric-topology

can any second homology class in an oriented smooth simply connected 4-manifold be represented by a closed smooth oriented surface of minimal genus?

For example we can find such a surface in $H_2(CP^2,Z)$, but I do not know in case of a rational 4-manifold, i.e.,  $X = CP^2\bar{CP^2}$.

Comment: If it can be represented by a closed surface at all, then it can be represented by one of minimal genus, no?

Comment: This has been answered at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/22473/request-intermediate-level-proof-every-2-homology-class-of-a-4-manifold-is-ge