# Every 4-manifold has a $\operatorname{Spin}^c$ Structure

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, dg.differential-geometry, gauge-theory

$\DeclareMathOperator\Spin{Spin}\DeclareMathOperator\SO{SO}$I'm having trouble understanding the proof given in Morgan's [*The Seiberg–Witten Equations and Applications to the Topology of Smooth Four-Manifolds*](https://doi.org/10.1515/9781400865161) that every 4-manifold $X$ admits a $\Spin^c$ structure (Lemma 3.1.2). One can easily see from the exact sequence:
\begin{equation*}
H^1(X;\Spin^c) \to H^1(X; \SO(n)) \oplus H^1(X;\mathbb{Z}) \xrightarrow{c_1+w_2} H^2(X;\mathbb{Z}_2)
\end{equation*}
that a $\Spin^c$ structure will exist iff $w_2(TX)$ lifts to an integral class, which we can check using Bockstein homomorphisms. After that, I'm lost; I'm not sure if these are theorems, or whether they are supposed to be obvious:

1. In what sense is every $\mathbb{Z}/2^k \mathbb{Z}$ 3-class represented by a mapping from a smooth $\mathbb{Z}/2^k \mathbb{Z}$-manifold into $X$?
2. Why are integral 2-classes that represent *torsion* elements necessarily represented by embedded oriented surfaces?

EDIT: Since the proof from Morgan's book is quite short, I may as well write out the whole thing here:

"We need only see that $w_2(X)$ lifts to an integral class $c \in H^2(X;\mathbb{Z})$ in order to prove the existence of a $Spin^c$ lifting. But for any class $x \in H_2(X;\mathbb{Z}/2 \mathbb{Z})$ the value of $w_2(X)$ on $x$ is given as follows: represent $x$ as an embedded (possibly non-orientable) closed surface in $X$ and take the self-intersection of this surface modulo two. To see that $w_2(X)$ lifts to an integral class, we must see that its integral Bockstein $\delta w_2(X)$ is zero. But this torsion integral class is zero if and only if it evaluates trivially on every $\mathbb{Z}/2^k \mathbb{Z}$ class of dimension three. Any such class is represented by a mapping of a smooth $\mathbb{Z}/2^k \mathbb{Z}$-manifold into $X$. The value of $\delta w_2(X)$ on such a class is equal to the value of $w_2(X)$ on the Bockstein of this $\mathbb{Z}/2^k\mathbb{Z}$-manifold. Thus, we need only see that $w_2(X)$ vanishes on integral classes which represent torsion elements in $H_2(X;\mathbb{Z})$. But this is clear, any such class is represented by a smoothly embedded oriented surface with zero self-intersection".

I suppose what I'm really asking is which statements in this proof are non-trivial theorems about the topology of 4-manifolds, and which ones are supposed to be obvious?

Sorry, I don't seem to be able to comment, so I'll just say here: [Ryan Budney](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/266946/every-4-manifold-has-a-spinc-structure#comment659920_266946), I hope this makes the question less vague, and [Anton Fetisov](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/266946/every-4-manifold-has-a-spinc-structure#comment660093_266946), yes, there are other proofs of this fact that I do understand, but I'm specifically trying to understand this proof, because it seems very slick.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Yes, I am familiar with the result of Thom, but I'm not aware of its extension to manifolds with a G-structure in Q1. Torsten's answer is nice but it seems to indicate that we didn't need the torsion condition at all in Q2.

Comment: Your question is rather vague.  Could you write it up in a way that doesn't require readers to go somewhere else?

Comment: Dimension 4 is required because any proof rests either on the Poincare duality (in compact case) or on the intersection form on 2-cohomology in general. Note that you also need orientability. I didn't read the paper you cite, but perhaps [this paper](http://people.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/teichner/Papers/spin.pdf) will help.

Comment: Another proof along these lines is given in a short note of Teichner and Vogt, http://people.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/teichner/Papers/spin.pdf. You might find the exposition there helpful.

Comment: The structure of Teichner's webpage has changed, and the original link is now broken.The most up-to-date version of Danny's link is https://people.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/teichner/Math/ewExternalFiles/spin.pdf

Comment: Note that the above argument seems to use the fact that the manifold is closed, while the Teichner-Vogt argument is for an **arbitrary** second countable oriented $4$-manifold (only the representability of a class in $H_2(M)$ by an embedded surface is used, which can be justified geometrically, without appealing to Thom's Theorem cf. Dylan Thurston's answer to [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/22473/request-intermediate-level-proof-every-2-homology-class-of-a-4-manifold-is-ge))

Comment: There seems to be no book by Morgan just called "The Seiberg–Witten equations", but there is one called "[The Seiberg–Witten Equations and Applications to the Topology of Smooth Four-Manifolds](https://doi.org/10.1515/9781400865161)" that has the result and proof you quote, so I changed the name accordingly.  Names of links: [@‍TorstenEkedahl's answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/22485) [referenced](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/659852) by @‍ChrisGerig; […](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1099687)

Comment: […](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1099686) [Teichner and Vogt - All 4-manifolds have $\operatorname{Spin}^c$-structures](https://people.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/teichner/Math/ewExternalFiles/spin.pdf) referenced by [@‍AntonFetisov](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/660093),[@‍DannyRuberman](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/660543), and [@‍mme](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/790952); [@‍DylanThurston's answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/22509) [referenced](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1099407) by @‍GustavoGranja.

Answer (score 5):

First let me stress the importance of Anton Fetisov's [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/266946/every-4-manifold-has-a-operatornamespinc-structure#comment660093_266946) that $X$ must be orientable. Indeed, this seems to be used at nearly every step of the proof you cite.

For example, consider the claim "for any class $x\in H_2(X;\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})$ the value of $w_2(X)$ on $x$ is given as follows: represent $x$ as an embedded (possibly non-orientable) closed surface in $X$ and take the self-intersection of this surface modulo two." This can fail if $X$ is non-orientable. For example, take $X=\mathbb{R}P^2\times\mathbb{R}P^2$, which has $w_2(X)=a^2\times 1 + a\times a + 1\times a^2$ where $a\in H^1(\mathbb{R}P^2;\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})$ is the generator. Consider the homology class $x\in H_2(X;\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})$ represented by the embedding $\iota:\mathbb{R}P^2\hookrightarrow \mathbb{R}P^2\times\mathbb{R}P^2$ of the first factor. Then
$$
\langle w_2(X),x\rangle =\langle w_2(X),\iota_*[\mathbb{R}P^2]\rangle = \langle \iota^*w_2(X),[\mathbb{R}P^2]\rangle = \langle a^2,[\mathbb{R}P^2]\rangle \equiv 1,
$$
whereas it is clear that the self-intersection is zero in this case.

Now to your actual questions:

1. **Edit: the answer below is incorrect (even with my assumed definition of $\mathbb{Z}/2^k\mathbb{Z}$-manifold), as pointed out by Gustavo Granja in the comments below.** <s>Here a $\mathbb{Z}/2^k\mathbb{Z}$-manifold means a manifold which is oriented with respect to singular homology with $\mathbb{Z}/2^k\mathbb{Z}$ coefficients. When $k=1$ this is all manifolds, and the claim reduces to Thom's positive answer to the mod $2$ Steenrod realizability problem. When $k>1$, a  $\mathbb{Z}/2^k\mathbb{Z}$-manifold is an orientable manifold $M^m$ with a choice of fundamental class $[M]\in H_m(M;\mathbb{Z}/2^k\mathbb{Z})$.
   By Thom's results, a homology class $a\in H_3(X;\mathbb{Z}/2^k\mathbb{Z})$ is represented by an *embedded* $\mathbb{Z}/2^k\mathbb{Z}$-manifold if and only if its Poincaré dual in $H^1(X;\mathbb{Z}/2^k\mathbb{Z})$ is induced from the universal Thom class $t_{\mathbb{Z}/2^k\mathbb{Z}}\in H^1(MSO(1);\mathbb{Z}/2^k\mathbb{Z})$ under some map $f: X\to MSO(1)$. Now note that $MSO(1)\simeq S^1$, and that the Thom class induces an isomorphism $$t^*_{\mathbb{Z}/2^k\mathbb{Z}}:H^1(MSO(1);\mathbb{Z}/2^k\mathbb{Z})\cong H^1(K(\mathbb{Z}/2^k\mathbb{Z},1);\mathbb{Z}/2^k\mathbb{Z}).$$ It follows that every $a\in H_3(X;\mathbb{Z}/2^k\mathbb{Z})$ is represented by an embedded $\mathbb{Z}/2^k\mathbb{Z}$-manifold.</s>

(Note that orientability of $X$ was used here, to get Poincaré duality with $\mathbb{Z}/2^k\mathbb{Z}$ coefficients.)

2. Again by orientability and Thom's results, every class in $H_2(X;\mathbb{Z})\cong H^2(X;\mathbb{Z})$ is represented by an embedded oriented surface $\Sigma\hookrightarrow X$. The torsion assumption is just used to get the final clause, that $\Sigma$ has zero self-intersection. This is because the self-intersection is Poincaré dual to cup square, and the square of a torsion class in $H^2(X;\mathbb{Z})$ is a torsion class in $H^4(X;\mathbb{Z})\cong \mathbb{Z}$, therefore is zero.

Comment: I think the argument at the end of 1) is not correct. A class in $H^1(X;\mathbb Z/2^k \mathbb Z)$ is induced from the generator of $H^1(MSO(1);\mathbb Z/2^k \mathbb Z)$ if and only if it comes from a homomorphism $H_1(X) \to \mathbb Z/2^k\mathbb Z$ which factors through $\mathbb Z$

Comment: Just to be clear: it is not true that any class in $H_3(X;\mathbb Z/2^k)$ can be represented by an embedded submanifold oriented with respect to singular homology with $\mathbb Z/2^k$ coefficients. For instance if $L^3(4)=S^3/(\mathbb Z/4)$ and $X=L^3(4)\times S^1$ only a multiple of the class in $H_3(X;\mathbb Z/4)$ corresponding to the $L^3(4)$ factor can be so represented. See [Danny Ruberman's comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/266946/every-4-manifold-has-a-operatornamespinc-structure/427604#comment1099693_427604) for the meaning of a $\mathbb Z/2^k$-manifold.

Answer (score 3):

This is an answer to 1. It is an edit of a previous answer based on the incorrect assumption that $\mathbb Z/k$-manifold means a closed manifold with a $\mathbb Z/k$-orientation. Thanks to Danny Ruberman for pointing out in the [comments](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/266946/every-4-manifold-has-a-operatornamespinc-structure/427604#comment1099693_427604) that a $\mathbb Z/k$-manifold is a type of manifold with singularities introduced by Morgan and Sullivan in [The transversality characteristic class and linking cycles in surgery theory](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/%7Ev1ranick/papers/morgsull.pdf).

Roughly, a $\mathbb Z/k$-manifold of dimension $n$ is obtained from  an oriented $n$-manifold with boundary whose boundary is partitioned into $k$ disjoint isomorphic closed $(n-1)$-manifolds by identifying the boundary pieces by orientation preserving diffeomorphisms. See section 2 of [$\mathbb Z_k$-stratifolds](https://arxiv.org/abs/1810.00531) by Andrés Angel, Carlos Segovia and Arley Fernando Torres for a more precise definition.

A $\mathbb Z/k$-manifold has a fundamental class in mod $k$ homology whose Bockstein is an integral fundamental class for the codimension 1 submanifold along which it is singular.

Given a CW complex $X$, any element of $H_n(X;\mathbb Z/2^k)$ is the image of the fundamental class of a $\mathbb Z/2^k$-manifold $M$ under some map $f \colon M \to X$. Here is a (possibly overcomplicated) justification:

Morgan and Sullivan show (or at least state, bottom of p. 471) that the bordism of $\mathbb Z/k$-manifolds is the homology theory represented by $MSO\wedge M\mathbb Z/k$ classifying cobordism with $\mathbb Z/k$-coefficients.

The spectrum $MSO_{(2)}$ is a wedge of suspensions of $H\mathbb Z/2$ and $H\mathbb Z_{(2)}$ and the canonical map $MSO_{(2)} \to H\mathbb Z_{(2)}$ splits. Smashing with the Moore spectrum $M\mathbb Z/2^k$ we see that the same is true of the map $MSO\wedge M\mathbb Z/2^k \to H\mathbb Z/2^k$. The (split surjective) induced map on homology sends a bordism class $[f \colon M \to X]$ to the image $f_*[M] \in H_*(X;\mathbb Z/2^k)$ of the fundamental class of the $\mathbb Z/2^k$-manifolds $M$. This completes the proof.

Note that this argument would not work for mod $l$ homology with $l$ not a power of $2$. See the paper by Angel, Segovia and Torres linked to above for more information and examples of $p$-torsion classes (with $p$ an odd prime) not represented by maps from $\mathbb Z/p$-manifolds.

Finally, see also Proposition 5.7.4 in Gompf and Stipsicz, [4-manifolds and Kirby calculus](https://doi.org/10.1090/gsm/020), for the original Hirzebruch–Hopf proof as well as a description of the Teichner–Vogt proof in [All 4-manifolds have $\operatorname{Spin}^c$-structures](https://people.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/teichner/Math/ewExternalFiles/spin.pdf) for arbitrary oriented $4$-manifolds linked to in the comments on the question ([1](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/266946/every-4-manifold-has-a-operatornamespinc-structure#comment660093_266946) [2](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/266946/every-4-manifold-has-a-operatornamespinc-structure#comment660543_266946) [3](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/266946/every-4-manifold-has-a-operatornamespinc-structure#comment790952_266946)). **Edit:** See also an interesting recent proof of LeBrun's in [Twistors, Self-Duality and Spin^c structures](https://doi.org/10.3842/SIGMA.2021.102) which is quite different from the proofs above. As written it only applies to compact $4$-manifolds but it is not hard to slightly adapt it so that it works for all $4$-manifolds.

Comment: I don't think you're interpreting `$\mathbb{Z}/r$ class' correctly. It's not a $\mathbb{Z}/r$-oriented closed $3$-manifold, but rather a map from an oriented 3-manifold with boundary whose boundary maps to a given surface with degree $r$. (Morgan-Sullivan, Ann. of Math. (2) 99 (1974), 463-544.) This gives a geometric representative of a non-integral class; the boundary around which it wraps r times is called the Bockstein. An example a dimension down would be $H_2(L(r,q),\mathbb{Z}/r) = \mathbb{Z}/r$, whose generator is represented by a null-homology of $r$ times the generator of $H_1(L)$.

Comment: @DannyRuberman That is very helpful, thanks! I will edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: Both this argument and LeBrun's are quite nice, thanks for your post.