# Geometric representatives of homology classes of manifolds

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, dg.differential-geometry, gt.geometric-topology

Is it true that for even dimensional differentiable manifold $M^{2n}$ all singular homology classes in dimension less than $n$ can be represented by a submanifold?

Comment: Look at the two answers to this duplicate question:http://mathoverflow.net/questions/21171/when-is-a-homology-class-represented-by-a-submanifold

Comment: In particular, there are obstructions for an integral homology class to be represented by a manifold map altogether (you can get some odd multiple in general), but as soon as that part works you can turn such a map into an embedding in the dimensions you're asking for.