# Are homotopy equivalent submanifolds also cobordant?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology

Let $M$ be a manifold, and let $A$ and $B$ be two submanifolds of $M$ which are diffeomorphic to each other.  I'll say $A$ and $B$ are *homotopy equivalent in $M$* if there is a $C^1$ function $f:A \times [0,1] \mapsto M$ such that $f(\cdot,0)$ is is the inclusion map for $A$ and $f(\cdot, 1)$ is the inclusion map for $B$ up to a diffeomorphism. My question is, under what circumstances does homotopy equivalence of $A$ and $B$ imply that $A$ and $B$ are *cobordant in $M$*  in the sense that there is a submanifold with boundary, $C$, obeying $\partial C=A\cup B$?  If $A$, $B$, $C$ need only be immersed submanifolds it seems like this might be true without further restriction, since we can define $C$ as the image of $f$, but if we require $A$, $B$, $C$ to be embedded submanifolds this construction will generically produce self-intersections in $C$ and it is not clear to me under what circumstances these can be "deformed away". Also as pointed out in the comments, even in the immersed case $f$ is not necessarily an immersion, so we still need to ask if it can be deformed into one.

Comment: The version of the question for immersions does not have an obvious answer as you suggest it does.  You can't always make a map an immersion using general position arguments.

Comment: You mean because the derivative matrix of $f$ might not have full rank?  Or did you have some other obstruction in mind?

Comment: A similar question was asked here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/27702/homologically-trivial-submanifolds/57642#57642 Note that the homotopy $f$ already gives a null-bordism of $A\cup B$, so you just have to decide if $f$ can be made an immersion (for which there is the Smale-Hirsch theory) and then an embedding (for which there are variants of the Whitney trick, as mentioned in Oscar's answer, but these will be highly sensitive to the dimension/codimension).