# Geometry Realization of Homology Class

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gn.general-topology, cobordism

Hello!
My question is about the realization of homology class.

The definition of the realizaion of homology class is: for manifold M and a homology class $z\in H_k(M)$, k is an integer. If we find a k-dimensional manifold N and a map $f:N \rightarrow M$ such that $f_* [N]=z$, $[N]$ is the fundamental class, then we call the homology class $z$ can be realized.

For this problem, Thom has the following theorem:

Thom[1954]  For every manifold M, consider a interger coefficient homology class $z\in H_*(M)$, that there exist a interger $l$ and $lz$ can be realized.

My Question is Simple:
  Why we should add this interger $l$?

Thom's original paper is written by French and I cann't understand it. Recently, I am reading a paper by A.Gaifullin:Combinatorial Realisation of Cycles and Small Covers and the result is related to Thom's paper.

Comment: As far as I can tell, Thom's paper is about realization by EMBEDDED submanifolds.

Comment: Well, Thom gives examples of compact differentiable manifolds where one cannot take $l=1$. Are you asking for an english explaination of these examples? 

Comment: Some torsion classes can not be realized as fundamental classes of manifolds, that's why $l>1$ can happen.  

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Duplicate of [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/1489/cohomology-and-fundamental-classes), which has a very good answer by Eric Wofsey.

Comment: Oh, that really helps me a lot, thank you!